# Mobile version of a website - Am i over thinking this?

Tags: mobile, web

i want my website to support mobile phones, but this is NOT an "how to" question.
i have read everything about that and to summerize my findings, @media tags and min/max-width.

now for the actualy question i have.
some of the website pages, get pretty large and include content, sidemenu, topmenu, footer, JS, CSS (for non mobile version) and so on.

but.... for a mobile version, i need to cut off at least 50% of it ( for example, a sidemenu should not be shown, footer should be smaller etc).

now, again, it is not a problem by css (just hiding the elements not needed for those with @media)
the real question is, why do i have to serve a full page, and show only parts of it ?
isnt it a waste of bandwidth ? loading speed will also be affected offcourse (loading a page specially designed for mobile, without all the "extra" features, would sum up in 10kb,
while the full-blown page can get up to 100kb).

am i over thinking this ?
should i just go with @media queries and dont care about wasted bandwidth ?

Comment: If your content loads with specific regions in a single 'master' page, then your mobile 'master' page excludes the unwanted regions. That's commonly how I go about it and make little use of the @media for content hiding.

Comment: @ericosg please have a look at the comment i wrote on Simon's answer.

Comment: Making a master page simply fills regions with content and has nothing to do with any content duplication. This would require that you have your content in separated views.

Comment: so, this gets me back to detecting the device and serving a masterpage based on that. which will include a redirect that is not really needed. or am i wrong?

Comment: you can avoid redirects if you use a method that allows the server to simply serve what you need based on the client's browser. this site http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ has all you need for any technology for detecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use case.

Would it take a very long time to make a separate mobile page(s)? if not then yes it would be better, why waste the bandwidth (big consideration to mobile devices possibly using 3 / 4g which they are going to pay for).

Keep in mind that a lot of the bigger websites do the traditional of redirecting to m."websitename" when on a mobile, so people do invest on having a mobile site and a full web based site.

long story short both are fine but its what suits you and what you have time for

Comment: the site has over 18,000 pages, its not really a problem to do another master page specific to mobile (like the big websites do),
but then, all pages will have duplicate content of the original full-blown site.

Comment: @CodeBlend i have considered that, but, after thinking about it for while it is not a good idea. i belive mobile search will get better and i believe there will be mobile only search (even now they exist). SEO would be really important and content will get weight on ranking.

Comment: well the content issue comes down to how the website is structured, would it be a case of you could reuse a lot of backend logic / classes and just have to make a new UI. If you could simply make a new mobile master page and then try feed it with the existing content then that would be how I would go. A lot of questions to be answered whether thats possible or not with ur design

Comment: it is easily pobssible, but how will i know which version of the masterpage to serve?

Comment: I work on the XPages team for IBM and we are making mobile web apps. We use the user agent string's to check and see if its mobile or not. eg. iphone will always have "iphone" in user agent, ipad has "ipad", and android has "android". And if you really want to get into full mobile support android phones have "android" and "mobile" while android tablets have just "android"

Comment: so you could either have and index page that works out which one or on the web version, redirect if mobile

Comment: and how do you handle the following?
"Cloaking: Serving different content to users than to Googlebot. This is a violation of our webmaster guidelines. If the file that Googlebot sees is not identical to the file that a typical user sees, then you're in a high-risk category. A program such as md5sum or diff can compute a hash to verify that two different files are identical." ?

Comment: No cloaking is doing something along the lines of providing a special html file only to bots with just a load of keywords to make your site show up higher on a search. This is not the same thing, this is providing a smaller UI wrapper for certain devices for them to access the web better. Your designing a second way for users to access the same content. You've nothing to worry about on that end because your not sending one thing to bots and one to users, both of these are for users